# Redirecionar boton login de Flutter

Tags: flutter

Tengo un widget loginbutton al cual necesito crearle una redireccion a la segunda pagina , tecnicamnte ya esta creada la redireccion pero a la hora de llamar al widget me dice k me falta un argumento posicional dentro de las comillas pero nose cual es , nose que necesita que le ponga hay 
para que funcione la lmada correctamente. Gracias un saludo.

```
Widget renderLoginButton(BuildContext context){

    return Container (
    height: 80,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:32),
    child: RaisedButton(
    color: Colors.white,
    textColor: Colors.cyan,
    child: Text(
      'LOG IN',
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 25
    ),
    ),
      onPressed:() {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Myappdos');
      },
      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
    ),
    ),
    );

  }


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:16 ),
            decoration:BoxDecoration(color: Colors.cyan),
            child: ListView(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:60 ),
              child: Image.asset
              ('assets/images/logo.png',
              width:230.0,
              height:230.0,
              ),
            ),

              renderEmailInput(),
              renderPasswordInput(),
              renderLoginButton(),//aki me dice k me falta ponerle un argumento dentro
              renderCreateAccountLink(),
              renderAvisoLegal()

          ]),
        ),
      );
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomendaría que buscaras información sobre como trabajar con funciones, ya que tu primero has definido tu función:

```
Widget renderLoginButton(BuildContext context){ //Aquí le dices que va a necesitar un parámetro de tipo BuildContext

    return Container (
    height: 80,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:32),
    child: RaisedButton(
    color: Colors.white,
    textColor: Colors.cyan,
    child: Text(
      'LOG IN',
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 25
    ),
    ),
      onPressed:() {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Myappdos');
      },
      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
    ),
    ),
    );

  }
```

Cómo le especificas que necesita un parámetro, cuando llamas a la función des de otra parte del código debes pasarle un parámetro del tipo que has deifindo:

```
renderLoginButton(),//Aquí debes pasarle el argumento de la función
```

Cómo necesita uno de tipo BuildContext y tu ya lo tienes dentro del Widget build le pasas context:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:16 ),
            decoration:BoxDecoration(color: Colors.cyan),
            child: ListView(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:60 ),
              child: Image.asset
              ('assets/images/logo.png',
              width:230.0,
              height:230.0,
              ),
            ),

              renderEmailInput(),
              renderPasswordInput(),
              renderLoginButton(context),
              renderCreateAccountLink(),
              renderAvisoLegal()

          ]),
        ),
      );
   }
 }
```

Comment: No habia caido en el parámetro context madre mia estoy ciego jjejeejej, muchas gracias un saludo!!